# is there a difference between .rmd and .Rmd files?

Tags: r, markdown

I wanted to know if there's a difference between .Rmd files and .rmd files (uppercase vs lowercase).
When I test it, there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: No there is not.  Some operating systems (looking at you, macOS!) think the two are the same.  If you look hard enough at enough R projects you will also see that while most use `.R` some do use `.r` and that too is the same to R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented above earlier, the short answer is 'no -- there is no difference'.

The larger context is that for *some* operating systems, `file.rmd` and `file.Rmd` are in fact the same as they are *on purpose* treating filenames in a case-insensitive matter.  (In hindsight that quite likely might not have been their brightest idea---but stuff happens and now it is a fact that is hard to undo.)  So R plays along and treats them the same way too.

You can even dig around existing R packages (and browsing *e.g.* at https://github.com/cran/ lets you view all CRAN packages via that 'mirror') and may notice that some packages do in fact use `file.r` even if most stick with `file.R`.  Again, they are treated the same by R, reflecting the fact that one of the operating systems R runs effectively enforces that.

Comment: I'm sure other people have horror stories too, but I remember getting **extremely** confused at one point using a program that was written for Windows (and made one set of assumptions/hacks about case sensitive filenames) on a Linux VM whose underlying file system was HGFS (MacOS) ...

Comment: I am sure you had similar issues too that you look at or work with the source code repos from other people and all of sudden it does not compiler because of a simple `#include <foobar.h>`  when on a grown-up operating system the file came in as `FooBar.h`.  Ouch.  And. Don't. Even. Ask. Me. About. Littler. And. Its. `r`. Binary.  It still hurts fifteen years later.